# A PostgreSQL array of varchar(custom_size) in Elixir's Ecto

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have an Ecto schema like this:

```
schema "quotes" do
  field :quote, :string
  field :tags, {:array, :string}

  timestamps()
end
```

In a corresponding migration there's:

```
create table(:quotes) do
  add :quote, :string, size: 145
  add :tags, {:array, :string}

  timestamps()
end
```

I want each tag in `tags` to be with a maximum size of 140. How to specify this constraint in the migration? My goal is to have an array of `varchar(140)` in a resulting PostgreSQL table instead of a more 'spacy' default ([255](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Migration.html#add/3)?).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`add` accepts any atom as the column type and passes it as-is to the Adapter and the PostgreSQL Adapter sends unknown types as-is to the database, which means we can specify the exact type, i.e. `varchar(140)` as the second element of `{:array, _}`, it just needs to be an atom.

```
add :tags, {:array, :"varchar(140)"}
```

I've tested this and running the migration correctly creates the column of the type need.

```
my_app_dev=# \d posts
                                  Table "public.posts"
  Column  |           Type           |                     Modifiers
----------+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------
 ...
 tags     | character varying(140)[] |
```

There's no need to change anything in the `schema`. The type there should remain `{:array, :string}`.